# Should the Blog link replace the Chat link?

Tags: discussion, user-interface

I noticed today that the Gaming.SE Blog seems to have staged a coup, overthrew, and finally usurped the Chat from its position along the page header.

Is there any reason why we've prioritized the one at the expense of the other? Is there something technical preventing from displaying both buttons? (I could have sworn they used to both be up there).

Comment: I don't think they've ever both been up there at once. If you were logged in you could see the chat link and if you were logged out you could see the blog link but not both.

Comment: @Mana maybe I'm thinking of the footer then...

Comment: Remember there's always the sidebar chat advertisement.

Comment: @badp - are you talking about the one on the main page? As far as I know, the main page (and the footer) are the only places that link to chat currently.

Answer (score 5):

This only happens for 24 hours when the blog post is new.

It's because there is a very limited amount of room in the topnav; for people with long names, rep, and lots of badges, it can easily wrap if we add just one more item.

(was not really an issue until we added the Stack Exchange multi-collider on the left, there.. that ate up a ton of space.)